# Utility java function to Convert a hive/sql data type to java data type string in java

Tags: java, sql, types, hive, type-conversion

I want to convert a data type string into java data type string.

How can I get a data type string for each of the following hive type string?

```
tinyint
smallint
int
bigint
boolean
float
double
string
array<int>
array<string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through it , hopefully it will help
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-TypeConversionFunctions